# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.javainuse.model.DAOUser cannot be cast to com.javainuse.dao.UserDao

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I run the application its not give an error but when hit the url on postman it showing error.

```
package com.javainuse.dao;


import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.javainuse.model.DAOUser;

@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<DAOUser, Integer> {
        UserDao findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: Return type for your method is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The return type should be your entity not your repository interface

I think your entity is `DAOUser`

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<DAOUser, Integer> {
    DAOUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```